# Namespace in method parameters

Tags: python, class, namespaces

I'm surprised that the namespace of function parameters in a method is the class and not the global scope.

```
def a(x):
    print("Global A from {}".format(x))

class Test:
    def a(self, f=a):
        print("A")
        f("a")  # this will call the global method a()

    def b(self, f=a):
        print("B")
        f("b")   # this will call the class method a()

t=Test()
t.b()
```

How to explain that? And how would I access the global a() from the parameters of b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace lookups always check the local scope first. In a method definition, that is the class.

At the time of the definition of `Test.a`, there is no local named `a`, only the global `a`. By the time `Test.b` is defined, `Test.a` has already been defined, so the local name `a` exists, and the global scope is not checked.

If you want to point `f` in `Test.b` to the global `a`, use:

```
def a(x):
    print("Global A from {}".format(x))

class Test:

    def a(self, f=a):
        print("A")
        f("a")  # this will call the global method a()

    def b(self, f=None):
        f = f or a
        print("B")
        f("b")   # this will call the class method a()

t=Test()
t.b()
```

which prints

```
B
Global A from b
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Yet, it's still new to me that the parameter namespace is different from the namespace in the method code...

Comment: Yeah, it was unexpected for me, too, until I got used to it.